# How to convert sql query to sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I query table A and table B.
How to query and pagination it?

I research using union all like:

```
select * from A
union all
select * from B
limit 50
```

But sequelize dont support union all.

Comment: From [sequelize repository](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8836) Beyond that there is no support for generating unions

Comment: remember that you can always pass a [raw SQL query](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html) to Sequelize as `db.sequelize.query(your_sql, { type: db.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT, replacements: {} })`

Comment: I find solution without raw query, if you can't find a way i using raw query. Tks @balexandre